# Accessing resultset using jstl in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to `Servlets/JSP`. I have built a Web application where I query db based on user input and store the `resultset` as session attribute.
Now when I try to access the result set using `JSTL` tag for each its giving error. I have used Derby as my db.
following is the code snippet.

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${sessionScope.borrow_list.rows}">
        <li>Name : <c:out value="${row.book}" /></li>
        <li>Author : <c:out value="${row.author}" /></li>
</c:forEach>
```

and this is the exception.

```
JspPropertyNotFoundException: /member_home.jsp(20,2) '${sessionScope.borrow_list.rows}' Property 'rows' not found on type org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet42
```

However I did see an example where the above code was used.
Am I doing something wrong or my db(ResultSet) doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: Don't send result set to you jsp. Create a bean class, i.e. book, loop through the resultset and assign value to the bean class and return the bean class to JSP instead.

Answer (score 0):

By the way from your code and error message you have given it seems - you have put `borrow_list.rows` in session from some where of your code. But the `borrow_list` doesn't contain any property called `rows`.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After the JDBC statement is executed, one has a ResultSet. That result set should be processed and then both ResultSet and Statement be closed.

Something like this:

```
public static class Tb {
    String a;
    int b;
    BigDecimal c;
}

List<Tb> borrowList = new ArrayList<>();

String sql = "SELECT a, b, c FROM tb WHERE a LIKE ? ORDER BY a"
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, searchKey + "%"); // First ?.
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
         while (rs.next()) {
             Tb record = new Tb();
             record.a = rs.getString("a");
             record.b = rs.getInt("b");
             record.c = rs.getBigDecimal("c");
             borrowList.add(record);
         }
    } // Closes rs.
} // Closes stmt.

request.setAttribute("borrow_list", borrowList);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").forward();
```

In the JSP you can then work normally.

It might be that in your found example a [RowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html) was used. Whereas ResultSet is something like an iterator, JdbcRowSet is like a list, heavier on the data.

Attributes can be helt in miscellaneous scopes: a request scope is just for this single request.

Make the class Tb `static` when defined as inner class of say the servlet class. This prevents there being a ServletClass.this being in Tb.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I get that this is the best solution i can implement for my program.